# Convert DateTime class to string

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, string, date

Currently I am retrieving a date from mssql with the data type of small date time.

The data is : `2013-03-12 00:00:00`

I want to store it in a variable and then display on a text box.

And the format I want to display is just `2013-03-12` on the text box.

The message I get is:

> catchable fatal error : Object of class DateTime could not be
>   converted to string.

Any idea?

Comment: Where is the query you tried that gave you that error? please post it.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with php or sql?

Comment: Select * from <table> where id = xxx

one of the column inside the table is smalldatetime type

Comment: @DanBracuk I am trying retrive the result and assign to php variable.

    $dateResult = $row[firstDate];

Comment: then you should use the convert function in Mahmoud's answer.  Then upvote it like I did and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in php you can simply use `date_format($date, 'Y-m-d')`

```
<?php
$date = date_create('2013-11-23 05:06:07');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
?>
```

returns 
2013-11-23

Answer (score 5):

The following code will give you a date usable for SQL:

```
$dateTime->format(\DateTime::ISO8601);
```

**-edit-**

Actually, I just saw that you want it the other way around. In that case:

```
$dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: I can't understand why this isn't the accepted answer...

Answer (score 2):

Use [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), datefield, 121)
FROM tablename;
```

Comment: I jusst replace the datefield with the column name i use in my database? What is 121?

Comment: @Genjo - It determine the style of the formated date for the conversion, with `121` it gives you the date in the format: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm`, then convert it to only `VARCHAR(10)` will give you: `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: I prefer to handle presentation in the presentation layer.